# Python 3.6: data is disordered when extracting it from a pdf table

Tags: python-3.x, dataframe, pdf, tabula

I'm trying to extract a dataframe from a PDF table using Tabula. I get data all jumbled together and I have trouble ordering it. Could anyone point out where my syntax is incorrect?

Images of the table and the output of my Python session:

[image]
<sup>(Click images to enlarge)</sup>

[image: output of my Python session]

Code:

```py
import tabulate as tabulate  
import tabula
from tabula import read_pdf
import pandas as pd
import camelot
a = read_pdf(r"C:\Users\Emege\Downloads\cencosud.pdf", pages = 6, guess = False,\
        encoding = "ISO-8859-1" ,output_format = "csv")

print(a)
a.to_csv("cen.csv", encoding = "utf-8")

b = camelot.read_pdf(r"C:\Users\Emege\Downloads\cencosud.pdf")
print(b)
```

Comment: ok, just give me a second to see what i can do.

Comment: If you prefer i´ll  send the link of the pdf file and the page is in the number six: http://s2.q4cdn.com/740885614/files/doc_financials/2018/03/Cencosud-Earnings-Release-4Q18-(ENG)-final.pdf.                                                                                                    ps: sorry, but i can put the image.

Comment: If you need anything else, please upload the image(s) to [imgur](https://imgur.com/) as either jpg or png, and provide a link to the image(s) in a comment and I'll add them to the question too.

Comment: I already answered a question about how to extract formatted text from images: https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/39397/ocr-software-for-linux/39409#39409. It will probably give you better results than Tabula.

Comment: Ohh i 'll check that, i need to install OCR in my computer?

Comment: You don't have to install anything; it's a web app.

Comment: I will try, thanks :) !!